# How to name keras model based on functional api

Tags: python, keras

I know how to set name of keras model when used sequential but I don't know how to name a functional api based model.
Let me re-phrase, I am asking how to set name of a **keras model** not the **layer**

---

## Solved

Well I experimented a little and it worked, so to name `functional api` based `keras` model, just pass the input in `Model` as follows:

```
Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense_out, name=name)
```

Comment: Please add an answer, don't add `[solved]` to the question. It is perfectly all right to answer your own question.

Comment: here a detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728083/change-the-model-name-given-automatically-by-keras-in-model-summary-output/62728323#62728323

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I experimented a little and it worked, so to name functional api based keras model, just pass the input in Model as follows:

```
Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense_out, name=name)
```

and its name can be excessed in similar way we access sequential one i.e.

```
model.name
```

Naming models comes in handy when you are working with bunch of models and want to save them all as well.

Comment: Remember that the given `name` should not include `Space`