# change the Model: <name> given automatically by keras in model.summary() output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When calling the command:

```py
print(model.summary())
```

I get the following output:

[image]

How can I rename the highlighted field, which is generated automatically by Keras?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is the argument 'name'

in functional format

```
inp = Input((10,))
out = Dense(1)(inp)

m = Model(inp, out, name='model_XXX')
m.summary()
```

in sequential format

```
m = Sequential([Dense(1, input_dim=10)], name='model_XXX')
m.summary()
```

if u have a pre-trained model you can simply do

```
m.fit(...)
m._name = 'model_XXX' # try with m.name if it raise error due to TF version
m.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, keras.Model(name="model_XXX") worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename an already built model, it can be done like this:

```
model.name = 'yourname'
```

Comment: Already tried this, but the ```model.name``` command changes the Sequential() object name, while I wanted to change the Model() object name. Sorry for the inconvenience. Just now I figured out that Sequential(), Model() object carry separate model names. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: @NikSp I am not sure what you are saying, I tried it with a Model instance and it worked fine.

Comment: Hmmm ok probably I did something wrong. I will double check it and let you know.